# how to remove all attributes with a group of elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to read the HTML of an element. but using this directly would come up with the element alongside with many attributes. I tried some code but unfortunately, it doesn't work. So please guys if you know any way else please provide

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Btn').click(function () {
                    var pureHtml = $('#Menu1 ul *').removeAttr('style').removeAttr('class').
                        removeAttr('tabindex').removeAttr('role').removeAttr('style').
                        removeAttr('float').removeAttr('width');

                    pureHtml = $(pureHtml).each('ul li *').removeAttr('class').
                        removeAttr('tabindex').removeAttr('role').removeAttr('style').
                        removeAttr('float').removeAttr('width');

                    pureHtml = $(pureHtml).each('ul li a *').removeAttr('class').
                        removeAttr('onclick').removeAttr('tabindex');

                    $('#show').html(pureHtml);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Can you give HTML?

Comment: Can you explicate "unfortunately, it doesn't work"?

Comment: Also jquery allows for multiple attributes so you do not have to keep repeating yourself. `.removeAttr('style role float')`

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to use jQuery. It's easy to do without:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.outerHTML);

div.addEventListener('click',
  (event) => { 
    removeAllAttributes(event.target);
    console.log(div.outerHTML)
  }
);

function removeAllAttributes(element) {
  if (!element instanceof HTMLElement) return;
  const attributes = [...element.attributes].map(x => x.localName);
  for (const attribute of attributes) {
    element.removeAttribute(attribute);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar" title="baz">Click me to remove all attributes</div>
```

Comment: How would you do this for a collection of possibly nested elements, like in the question?

Comment: Edited the answer so you have a function that removes the attributes.